# I want to learn how to make a large script into smaller scripts which work together using the Page Object Model structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec

I would like break this large script down into smaller scripts that follow the [Page Object Model](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) structure and work with each other. What is the best way to do this? Basically my script pulls login credentials from a CSV file and logs in, then checks to see if the page has the correct links loaded.

```ruby
   require 'CSV'
   require 'selenium-webdriver'
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'rspec'
   require 'securerandom'

         # Base class for Login methods. Subclasses should override this behavior
         # where appropriate.

         class DataEmail <
           Struct.new(:email, :password) 
         end

           $i = 1
           $num = 3

         while $i < $num do
           read_data = CSV.read('emailcsv.csv')
           read_data.each do |line|
           words = line

           p = DataEmail.new
           p.email = words[0]
           user = p.email

           p.password = words[1]
           pass = p.password

           describe 'Merchantcentric' do
               before(:all) do
                   @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
                   @browser.get "https://meffff.com/session/new"
                   @wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) 
               end

               it 'Verify that login dispays ' do
                   @wait.until{@browser.find_element(:id, 'email')}
                   @browser.find_element(:id, 'email').displayed?
                   #Verify login at merchant site
                   @browser.find_element(id: "email").send_keys user
                   @browser.find_element(id: "password").send_keys pass
                   @browser.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@class='button primary']").click
               end

               it 'Verify that Manage Offers is present in the side nav ' do
                   @wait.until {@browser.find_element(id:'nav-deals')}
                   @browser.find_element(id:'nav-deals').displayed?
               end

               it 'Verify that Redeem Vouchers is present in the side nav ' do
                   @wait.until {@browser.find_element(id:'nav-customers')}
                   @browser.find_element(id:'nav-deals').displayed?
               end

               it 'Verify that Engage Customers is present in the side nav ' do
                   @wait.until {@browser.find_element(id:'nav-engage')}
                   @browser.find_element(id:'nav-deals').displayed?
               end

               it 'Verify that View Payments is present in the side nav ' do
                   @wait.until {@browser.find_element(id:'nav-accounting')}
                   @browser.find_element(id:'nav-deals').displayed?
                   @browser.quit
              end

           end

          $i +=1 

       end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a big question really! There are so many different approaches to the page object model - I'll try to give you an example that sorta fits with the code that you posted. It won't cover 100% what you need, but should give you an idea of the sort of thing you can do.

Firstly, you need to abstract your browser stuff. You want tests themselves to be build of page object calls and no direct calls to the browser itself. This means that you can change the stuff behind the scenes without having to edit your tests.

```
#
# The web browser.
#
module Browser
  #
  # Starts the browser.
  #
  # @return [Void]
  def self.start
    @browser ||= Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  end

  #
  # Closes the browser.
  #
  # @return [Void]
  def self.close
    @browser.quit
  end

  private

  #
  # A catch all method to pass WebDriver requests through to our browser object.
  #
  # @return [Void]
  def self.method_missing(method, *arguments)
    @browser.send(method, *arguments)
  end
end
```

This provides us with a basic way of talking to the browser. We can start and stop it, and also run Selenium WebDriver methods through this module.

Next a basic page object module:

```
# Basic page object module. You will expand upon this a lot.
#
module PageObject
  #
  # Creates a class method that will return the selector and reference
  # of an element
  #
  # @param name [Symbol] name of the method
  # @param params [Hash<String>] element selector (key) and reference (value)
  def element(name, params)
    send(:define_method, name) do
      params
    end
  end

  #
  # Types into specified element.
  #
  # @param element [Hash] the element selector and reference
  # @param text [String] the text to type
  def type(element, text)
    Browser.find_element(element).send_keys text
  end

  #
  # Clicks on the specified element.
  #
  # @param element [Hash] the element selector and reference
  # @return [Void]
  def click(element)
    Browser.find_element(element).click
  end
end
```

Next an example page object. I've used your example of the login page.

```
#
# Page object representing a log in page. This is the bit that will contain all
# methods related to specific pages.
#
class LogInPage
  include PageObject

  element :email_field, id: 'email'
  element :password_field, id: 'password'
  element :submit_button, css: '.button.primary'

  #
  # Logs in using the specified user credentials.
  #
  # @param email [String] the users email address
  # @param password [String] the users password
  # @return [Void]
  def log_in_with!(email, password)
    type email_field, text: email
    type password_field, text: password
    click submit_button
    # Some approaches will return another page object at this point.
    # You can do this if you want, but personally I think it leads to confusing
    # tests.
  end

  #
  # Checks if a user is logged in.
  #
  # @return [Boolean]
  def user_logged_in?
    # This should return true or false depending on if a user is logged in.
    # Login page may not be the correct place for this, but it'll do for this
    # example.
  end
end
```

Your test might look something like:

```
describe 'Merchantcentric' do
  context 'User Login' do
    before :all do
      Browser.start
      Browser.get 'https://meffff.com/session/new'
      # Ideally all this browser creation stuff would be abstracted
      # out of your tests and into something else (spec_helper maybe?)
      @page = LogInPage.new
    end

    after :all do
      Browser.close
    end

    it 'success' do
      # I purposely left out your csv stuff - you should probably
      # have that separate to your tests also. I am assuming that
      # user and pass will be coming from somewhere.
      @page.log_in_with! user, pass
      assert(@page.user_logged_in?, 'User was not logged in successfully')
    end
  end
end
```

These would all obviously be inside different files! I've run out of lunch break time now, so if you have any questions let me know, I'm always available to chat about this stuff! Also apologies if some of this stuff doesn't work... I wrote it without testing but it *should* be ok(ish)!

Also, you shouldn't need to check for element presence before you interact with them. If the element isn't there, the test should fail anyway with a Selenium exception.

What made you settle on Rspec for your functional browser tests btw? Did you explore other options such as Cucumber?

#### Update

In regard to your comment:

In the example you've given, you could create a new method in your PageObject class called `element_exists?` and create a method inside your `LogInPage` class (for example) called `deals_present?`. You'd use this method in your assertion.

Your `element_exists?` method would be simple:

```
#
# Checks if an element exists, returning true or false.
#
# @params params [Hash] the selector and reference for the element
# @return [Boolean]
def element_exists?(params)
  Browser.find_elements(params).any?
end
```

Your ‘deals_present’ method could look something like:

```
#
# Checks if the deals element is present on the page.
#
# @return [Boolean]
def deals_present?
  element_exists? deals_navigation
end
```

You’d obviously need to create the deals_navigation page element using the ‘element’ method described in my post.

I notice that you want to have a wait.until before you check for the deals element. Again, you’ll want to abstract this out into your PageObject class and then perhaps call it inside your deals_present? method. I’ll let you work this one out, but let me know if you have too much trouble with it.

Your test assertion with all this done would look something like:

```
expect(!@page.deals_present?)
```

This will fail if the deals element is displayed. The benefit of doing it this way is you're removing the majority of the logic from the tests themselves which means if the logic changes, you just need to update it in a single place rather than all the tests that use it.

Comment: Thanks so much david ambler one other question the assertion below verifies if the link is present. Whats the best way to verify the link is NOT present.



Maybe something like

                      it 'Verify that View Payments is present in the side nav ' do
                                 wait.until {browser.find_element(id:'nav-accounting')}
                                 browser.find_element(id:'nav-deals').displayed?.should == false
                                browser.quit
                        end

Comment: I've updated the Answer with a method of doing this. Let me know if it doesn't make sense (it's early in the morning!).

Comment: Thanks so much for you expertise  I have created 4 different scripts with small methods following your examples above. I have 2 questions where do I put the require 'rubygem' and the looping logic to parse through a CSV to get the email and password `class DataEmail <`? Also what file do I run first to execute these scripts? Once I do these two updates I think I should be ready to execute.  

      class DataEmail <
        Struct.new(:email, :password) 
      end

Comment: You'll likely want to put your requires into your spec_helper file. Checkout http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec--net-21297 for a quick tutorial on how to get an rspec project set up. This will also tell you how you should be running your tests. As for the CSV part, you'll probably want to make a library file containing your logic for doing this and then call it at the beginning of your test, looping over the data in the CSV file. If you're happy with my answer, remember to accept the answer on this page!

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your scenario into three parts.

- Create a new file for all universal functions like a library. Write down a universal function for pulling data from .csv files.
- Create a test suite just to validate login functionality using the above universal function.
- Create a test suite to check if the page has the correct links loaded.

[More on Page-Object model](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern). Hope this helps.